# Mismtach Error in Foxpro SQL insertion

Tags: visual-foxpro

I need someone could help me out on how to trace the error of "mismatched data type" in visual foxpro 6.0 When I issues a command like this "insert into tmpcur from memvar".

tmpcur is a cursor having bulk numbers of columns and it is ready hard to trace which one is having mismatch in data type for insertion problem.

It is pretty difficult to trace the insertion loop of each record into VFP tables one by one unliked MSSQL profiler.

Appreciate to someone could help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This should help you.  I have a temp cursor created with some bogus field / column names testing for types of character, integer, double, currency, date and time.  Trying to follow what is the result of your scenario, I am taking the memory variable of "bbbb" which should be double (or numeric at the least), and changed it to a string.

I am then HOLDING the error trapping routine that MAY be in effect, then setting my own (as I don't think try/catch existed in VFP6.. it may, but I just don't remember.  So, I did an ON ERROR, set a variable to true.  Then, I default it to false, try the insert, then check the flag.  If the flag IS set, then I go into a loop and try for each column in the given table/alias (in my example it is "C_Tmp", so replace with your table/alias).  It goes through each variable, and if the data type is different from the table structure, it will dump the column name and table / memory value for you to review.

You could put this to a log file or something.

Now, another consideration.  Some types are completely valid and common for implied conversion, such as character and memo fields can both get strings.  Integer, double, float, currency can all work with generic "numeric" values.
So, if you encounter these differences, then we can go one level further and look for comparable types, but let me know and we can adjust as needed.

At least this should give you a huge jump to your insert issue.

```
CREATE CURSOR C_tmp ( cccc c(10), iiii i, bbbb b(2), ccyyyy y, ddd d, tttt t )
SCATTER MEMVAR memo
m.bbbb = "wrong data type, was double with 2 decimal"


lcHoldError = ON("ERROR")
ON ERROR lFailInsert = .t.
lFailInsert = .f.

INSERT INTO C_Tmp FROM memvar

IF lFailInsert
    FOR lnI = 1 TO FCOUNT( "C_Tmp" )
        lcTmp = FIELD( lnI, "C_Tmp" )
        IF NOT TYPE( "C_Tmp." + lcTmp ) == TYPE( "m.&lcTmp" )
            ? "Invalid " + lcTmp + ", C_Tmp.&lcTmp, m.&lcTmp    
        ENDIF 
    ENDFOR 
ENDIF 

ON ERROR &lcHoldError
```